# How to return Virtual Attribute PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, propertyinfo

I'm having difficulty returning the attributes of a virtual value in my entity model, does anyone know how I can return the PropertyInfo of this virtual attribute?

I have the following entities:

**Entities**

```
public class Company 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

However I am not able to access the attributes of the Owner model when returning the Owner PropertyInfo in the Model Company.

**Basic example:**

```
public PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo()
{
   Type tType = typeof(Company);
   PropertyInfo prop = tType.GetProperty("Owner.Name");

   return prop;
}
```

> The variable **prop** returns **null**

Am I forgetting to implement something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get `Owner` property first then get the `Name` through it:

```
var owner = tType.GetProperty("Owner");

var name = owner.PropertyType.GetProperty("Name");
```

Or just get it directly if you have access to `Owner`:

```
var name = typeof(Owner).GetProperty("Name");
```

Comment: Work fine for me! Thank you.